# changing form method with js on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the method attribute of my form with javascript (jQuery or pure).

My form has method="post", i try to change it with:

```
$("#submit-button").click(function(){ 
    var url = $('input[id=url]').val();
    var method = $('#method option:selected').val();
    $("#form-test").attr("action", url); 
    $("#form-test").attr("method", method);
    $("#form-test").submit();
});
```

This code works on Chrome and I8 but not on Firefox. 
The action is set correctly and also method variable contains "get" or "post" correctly.
Any idea?

**SOLVED:** I was using an old version of jquery (copy&paste fault), i've upgraded to 1.7.1 and now it works, with the same code...

Comment: Is "form" the ID of your form ? Think you are missing this.

Comment: yes, form was the id of the form. now i changed to form-test

Answer (score 15, accepted):

this is my code, and it works just fine on both IE/FF/Chrome

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeMethod() {
    $("#myPost").attr("method", "get");
}
</script>

<form method="post" id="myPost">
    <input type="text" name="abc" id="abc" value="Something" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="changeMethod()" />
</form>
```

Comment: I've updated my code, now it should be equivalent to the your. But method is not changed.

Comment: Which version of firefox are u running on? I tested on FF10. Maybe there are difference between versions.

Comment: I was using FF8 but now i've upgrade to FF10. Seems to be the same... $("#form-test").attr("method", method); doesn't change the method attribute of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#form").attr("method", "get");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need put code after you declaration of form.

```
<form id="form"> ... </form>
<script>
   $("#form").attr("method", "get");
</script>
```

Comment: I need to change at the submit time.

Comment: Ok. test your $('#method option:selected').val() and view your return. If use select tag, remember, you need select item list to command work fine.

Comment: Thanks Jones but i'm sure that $('#method option:selected').val() returns exactly what i expect.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can write the code like this

```
$("#myPost").prop("method","get")
```